# Chess software that can show all legal moves?

Tags: software

I'm a casual player, and I learned chess from my Dad when I was a kid, but I still have the problem that I miss really obvious moves I can make (or I don't see really obvious moves the other side can make.)

Is there a chess GUI out there that has a feature that shows all the legal moves possible on the board at a time? Like as arrows pointing from the pieces to squares or something like that?

Comment: On windows, Linux, android,...?

Comment: Seeing ALL legal moves is likely to be useless since in most positions the number of legal moves is too large: the board will be essentially covered with arrows.

Answer (score 1):

I believe most sophisticated GUI would have the feature to:

- highlight possible moves for any piece; i.e. if you click (or hover) on a piece it will highlight all possible destination squares
- highlight attacked pieces
- highlight the last move

Arena and chesspad and many others should be able to do this.

Showing all possible moves is not useful as there are far too many in most positions, that you would not see anything anyway.

If you want to play online, also the lichess client (and probably others) can highlight moves.

Answer (score -1):

Try chesspad. It is small and can highlight the available squares for a piece. Another alternative is Arena.

Comment: Do you mean this [chesspad](http://www.wmlsoftware.com/chesspad.html)? For both chesspad and Arena, can you explain what settings need to be used to highlight alternatve squares for a piece? That would make your answer more useful (and could bring some upvotes).

Comment: Both programs have a configuration option were you can activate or desactive, at your will. Nothing special about that.